# How do I properly assign integers in an array?

Tags: arrays, sorting, integer, variable-assignment, pascal

Im currently trying to make a binary insert program, it reads a random number and inserts it in a sorted list, but every time I execute the program it just returns a list full of 0's I had this problem too when creating a normal insertion one. Even before sorting the list is full of 0's (aka no elements are ever assigned for some reason)

Here's the code:

```
program BinaryInsert;

function binaryfind(head, tail : integer; e : integer; vector: array of integer) : integer;  //uses binary search to find the right placement for e (element) inside the vector
var
    mid : integer;
begin
    mid := (head + tail) div 2;  //keep in mind that div returns the value rounded down
    if head <> tail then
    begin
       if vector[mid] >= e then  //>= garantees that this sorting method is stable
         binaryfind(mid+1, tail, e, vector)
       else
         binaryfind(head, mid, e, vector);
    end
    else
    begin
       if e >= vector[mid] then
         binaryfind := mid + 1  //it should take the place in front of mid (again >= garantees stability)
       else
         binaryfind := mid;  //it should take the place before mid
    end;
end;

procedure swap(e1, e2: integer);
var
    aux : integer;
begin
    aux := e1;
    e1 := e2;
    e2 := aux;
end;

procedure binaryinsert(e : integer; vector : array of integer);  //actual sorting happens here
var
    i, placement, l : integer;
begin
    l := Length(vector);
    placement := binaryfind(0, l-1, e, vector);
    vector[l] := e;
    for i := (l-1) downto (placement + 1) do
       swap(vector[i], vector[i-1]);  //reorganizes the array until the new element is at the correct placement
end;

procedure randomsorted(vector : array of integer);  //creates a sorted array with n random numbers
var
  i : integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to Length(vector)-1 do
       binaryinsert(random(9999), vector);
end;

var
  vector : array of integer ;
  e : integer;
begin
  SetLength(vector, 5);
  randomsorted(vector);
  for e in vector do
    writeln(e);
  readln(e);
end.
```

I was trying to get a list of sorted random integers

Comment: First of all, I don't get what your `binaryfind` needed for when you then still iterate over all all elements from the end to its final position ... Second: check what your `binaryfind` returns. Most certainly it doesn't return what you expect it to return, because 1) you don't use the result of your recursive call. I'd expect something like `tmp := binaryfind(...)` (but I admit my pascal is a bit rusty, so it might work diffent than other languages)  2) binary search won't work on an array like `1 5 0 0 0`, because it's not sorted. It always return 32585 for me

Comment: And as for all such basic algorithms: Lean how to use a debugger. Try to understand your algorithm and what it should return in specific situations. Then use a debugger and strep through your program and you will see, when your program starts to differ from the expected results ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: Note that `swap` effectively does nothing as written. You need to pass `e1` and `e2` as `var`. E.g. `procedure swap(var e1, e2: integer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations: the call to `random(9999);` without a previous call to `Randomize()` always returns 0 as the first value in my test. For a true (semi)random series you should call `Randomize()` at beginning of the program.

However, during development, it might be useful to feed selected constant values, just to verify that the sorting works as it should.

Pay attention to the difference between `Value` and `Variable` parameters. You are passing `vector` in two places as a value parameter, but you want to retain the changes you do to the array, ergo, you should pass `vector` as a variable parameter.

Finally it seems `binaryinsert()` and `binaryfind()` need some attention. You are assigning new values to `vector[l]`, which is past the end of the array. There might be other problems too.

Comment: yeah the code still doesn't work so clearly there are other problems, but thanks for bringing those things to my attention, my teacher suddenly asked us to use pascal so many things just escaped me as I tried to learn it asap.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I noticed that in `binaryinsert` you are swapping items *unconditionally* in the `for` -loop. Probably you should swap only if `verctor[i] > vector[i-1]`. If you have further problems, post a new question with current code, and I will have a look. Also note the comment by @Chris.